# How to handle xss attack on search input field in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl, xss, jstl-functions

How to add c:out for input search box ?

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
```

Now if the user enters some invalid string(">) in the text box, the html renders it and impacting the UI

```
I tried adding, 
    <input type="text" name="search" value="<c:out value=""/>" id="search" />
but not working for input search boxes.
```

Please give me some suggestions 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the entire code?

Comment: If you are using jsp and servlet then you can use filter for that